# How can I use a type annotation to specify a variable in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, testing, visual-studio-code, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I am running test cases for functions I created in Haskell. I created a function called zip3Lists. It takes in any type (polymorphic arguments) of three lists and returns list of 3-tuples where each 3-tuple consists of the elements from each list consecutively. For instance, zip3Lists [1, 2, 3][4, 5, 6][7, 8, 9] would produce [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)].

When testing the function, in my spec file, I have the following code to test when the function is used with 3 empty lists.

I get this long error on ‘shouldBe’ even though it matches my function return value:

```
Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘shouldBe’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 45 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘zip3Lists [] [] [] `shouldBe` []’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        it "produces the list  []" $ zip3Lists [] [] [] `shouldBe` []
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘do it "produces the list  []" $ zip3Lists [] [] [] `shouldBe` []
            it "produces the list  []"
              $ zip3Lists [1, 2, ....] ['a', 'b', ....] [] `shouldBe` []
            it "produces the list  []"
              $ zip3Lists [1, 2, ....] [] [4, 5, ....] `shouldBe` []
            it "produces the list  [(1, 'a', 4), (2, 'b', 5), (3, 'c', 6)]"
              $ zip3Lists [1, 2, ....] ['a', 'b', ....] [4, 5, ....]
                  `shouldBe` [(1, 'a', 4), (2, 'b', 5), ....]
            ....’
   |        
13 |       zip3Lists [] [] [] `shouldBe` []
```

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You can for example specify that the list should be a list of 3-tuples of `Int`s with:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = do
  describe "zip3Lists" $ do
    it "produces the list  []" $
      zip3Lists [] [] [] `shouldBe` ([] :: [(Int, Int, Int)])
```

Or you can work with the [**`TypeApplications`** extension <sup>[haskell.org]</sup>](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html#extension-TypeApplications):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

spec :: Spec
spec = do
  describe "zip3Lists" $ do
    it "produces the list  []" $
      zip3Lists @Int @Int @Int [] [] [] `shouldBe` []
```

Comment: Can I also make the types polymorphic? For example, ([] :: [(a, a, a)])?

Comment: @Jesuit: but the entire problem here is that Haskell doesn't know for which `a`s it should apply this, and therefore thus errors.

Comment: @Jesuit A koan: all code that runs is monomorphic.

Comment: @DanielWagner I have to disagree on that :-D. Let's say "most code that runs".

Comment: @chi Cool! What code have you got in mind that runs without having chosen its type?

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm mostly joking and "arguing semantics" a bit. What I do not fully like of that koan is that it sounds like it's claiming that after compilation all types are monomorphic, say like C++ templates (or Rust generics) are instantiated at compile time. In Haskell, polymorphic data survives at runtime.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm mostly thinking about pathological cases like `f :: Show a => Int -> a -> String ; f 0 x = show x ; f n x = f (n-1) (Just x)`, where there is no way to pre-generate a finite set of monomorphic instances for `a` (as in C++ and Rust), but we need to keep the polymorphic code until runtime.

Comment: @chi Okay. I can see why you object: the compiler frequently produces code which works correctly at many types, and *which* monomorphic type it's chosen to run at may not be known during compilation. Whether you consider that "polymorphic code" is indeed something of a semantic question. I think I'm going to stand by my claim, but it is a very fine point!

Comment: @Jesuit: If you want a concrete type that’s in some way less arbitrary than `Int`, you could choose `[Void]` (`@Void` / `[] :: [Void]` / `vacuous []`), since `Void` has no defined values, so if fully evaluated, the list *must* be empty. The extended defaulting rules that are enabled by default in GHCi would select `()` here, which is also a reasonable choice imo.